# Android - How to accept any certificates using HttpClient and passing a certificate at the same time

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate, httpclient

I have a scenario in which I must pass a certficate to my server, then the server sends me his certificate, which I must accept to access the server. I was using HttpURLConnection for this, with no problems.

However, I recently had a problem with HttpURLConnection. The code I was using retrieved an image from a HTTPS server. If the image was small (< 500kb), no problem whatsoever occured. However, with larger images I got this:

javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x3c97e8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

I was reading about it on the Internet, and many people said that using HttpClient instead of HttpURLConnection was the way to go (an example is this site http://soan.tistory.com/62 , think that is written in korean, I can't read it but that's what I think it says).

This is my old code, using URLConnection:

```
    public static URLConnection CreateFromP12(String uri, String keyFilePath,
        String keyPass, TrustManager[] trustPolicy, HostnameVerifier hv) {
    try {

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");

        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyFilePath),
                keyPass.toCharArray());

        kmf.init(keyStore, keyPass.toCharArray());
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustPolicy, null);

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext
                .getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }

    URL url;
    URLConnection conn;
    try {
        url = new URL(uri);
        conn = url.openConnection();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }

    return conn;
}
```

And this is the new one, using HttpClient:

```
public class HttpC2Connection {

public static HttpEntity CreateHttpEntityFromP12(String uri,
        String keyFilePath, String keyPass) throws Exception {

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyFilePath), keyPass.toCharArray());

    SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(keyStore);
    sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();

    registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

    ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,
            registry);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    return entity;
}
```

But now, using HttpClient, my server returns me an error saying that I must pass a certificate, so I guess that

```
SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(keyStore);
```

isn't loading my certificate.

So, how can I do the following two things at the same time:

1.) Pass a certificate to my server;
2.) Accept any certificate from my server

Using the HttpClient class?

PS: I'm using Android 3.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Don't* just accept any certificates. *Don't* use home-made `SSLSocketFactory`'s that compromise security. Use the [SSLSocketFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) from the SDK, and pass both a trust store (containing the server certificate or the CA certificate that issued it) and a keystore (containing your client certificate and private key). You can use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#SSLSocketFactory%28java.security.KeyStore,%20java.lang.String,%20java.security.KeyStore%29) constructor to achieve this, the JavaDoc has details on how to create the key stores.

Comment: Thank you, Nikolay. I will take a look. But in my case there is no big deal into accepting any certificates because I'm running in Test environment. Anyway, I will take a look and post feedback.

Comment: Thanks, Nikolay. For anyone who got the same problems, reading this: http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html was very useful, too.

Answer (score 2):

The following code disables SSL certificate checking for any new instances of HttpsUrlConnection:

https://gist.github.com/aembleton/889392

```
/**
 * Disables the SSL certificate checking for new instances of {@link HttpsURLConnection} This has been created to
 * aid testing on a local box, not for use on production.
 */
private static void disableSSLCertificateChecking() {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }
    } };

    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```